# Regular Expression to Add Space After 10 Digits

Tags: regex, find-and-replace, text-manipulation

How would I go about writing a regular expression to do a find/replace operation in order to add a space after 10 digits of ever number that is 20 digits long?

I have a long list of phone numbers where some of them are accidentally 20 digits long and I need to add a space in between each instance of that.

**Edit**: I tried \d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d which selects 20 digit numbers, but replacing that with a space will just replace all 20 digits with blank whitespace rather than inserting a space after 10 digits.

I am attempting to do this with Sublime Text on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: Modified my question and added what I have tried so far and what I am using for this.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use [Capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) if you want to perform replacement operations while preserving components of the original string.

your regex would follow something like:

pattern:  `"^([\d]{10})([\d]{10})" //two groups of 10`

replace:  `"$1 $2"`

The parentheses around each pattern for a block of ten, define a capture group. so we are saying, "the first ten digits in group $1, and the second 10 are in group $2". then we just say "print group 1, add a space, and print group 2".

Note that each platform is different in terms of its Regex syntax and replace syntax. many use `$number` (like sed), others use `\number` (like notepad++), so be sure to consult the documentation for your product.